# Terraform HTTP not working getting error as - on main.tf line 1, in data "http" "example"

Tags: http, terraform

I have taken code from 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/http/data_source.html
but its throwing error.

```
data "http" "example" {
  url = "https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform"

  # Optional request headers
  request_headers = {
    Accept = "application/json"
  }
}


Command : terraform plan
Error: Error during making a request: https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform

  on main.tf line 1, in data "http" "example":
   1: data "http" "example" {
```

Error:
Error: Error during making a request: https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform

on main.tf line 1, in data "http" "example":
   1: data "http" "example" {

Comment: Can you show the full output when you are running things? And what are you running to get that error? A plan? An apply?

Comment: Getting above error after running command -                                          
 terraform plan                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                     
 Error: Error during making a request: https://httpbin.org/get

  on main.tf line 29, in data "http" "example":
  29: data "http" "example" {

Comment: That's the full error?

Comment: yes its full error . I have copied code from link - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/http/data_source.html   and running as it. It should work. Not getting whats wrong there.